# Run Python File in Terminal fails, & was unexpected

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error in visual studio code every time I try to use the 'Run Python File in Terminal' choice in the pop up menu for every python file that 
I have.

> I:\Python\HelloWorld>&
>   C:/Users/jdhoc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe
>   i:/Python/HelloWorld/helloworld.py & was unexpected at this time.

[image]

I can still go to the terminal and do: python helloworld.py, for example, and that works.
This issue started right after I installed the emojisense extension and added some settings to my settings.json file.

```
"emojisense.languages": {
        "markdown": true,
        "plaintext": {
            "markupCompletionsEnabled": false,
            "emojiDecoratorsEnabled": false
        },
        "git-commit": true
    },
"emojisense.unicodeCompletionsEnabled": true,
"emojisense.markupCompletionsEnabled": true,
```

I removed the lines from setting.json that I added for emojisense and that did not work.  I also uninstalled visual studio code and reinstalled and that did not fix the issue either.  I have included my settings.json file as well.  I am sure I probably messed something up when I copied the emojisense stuff into settings.json but I am unsure of how to fix it now.

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
{
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.pythonPath":"C:\\Users\\jdhoc\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.fontSize":16,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "ayu",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Predawn",
    "workbench.settings.editor": "json",
    "workbench.settings.openDefaultSettings": true,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats":[
        {
            "format": "compressed",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "/dist/css"
    }],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false,
    "prettier.jsxSingleQuote": true,
    "prettier.singleQuote": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[python]": {

    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to provide the most important bit of informaiton - what's the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi Don, the error is included in the post just under the first sentence in the yellow box.  I:\Python\HelloWorld>& C:/Users/jdhoc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe i:/Python/HelloWorld/helloworld.py & was unexpected at this time.  I guess it was more of a notification than an error, :).

Answer (score 1):

It's not just a notification, it's a bug in the latest Python-Extension release since the python interpreter won't start unless you delete the additional & in front of the command manually in the terminal. And it's not related to emojisense.

You can find another (duplicate) post regarding this issue here:
[Ampersand “&” syntax error running any Python script in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456924/ampersand-syntax-error-running-any-python-script-in-vscode)

The issue has been solved now with release 2019.5.18678 (5 June 2019) of the Python extension.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks very much for the info, much appreciated!

Comment: Seems as the bug has returned with v2021.4.765268190 of Python extension. Everything worked well until recently but now the extension is trying to run `PowerShell` virtualenv activation script (`Activate.ps1` instead of `activate.bat`) even when using `cmd` and is inserting `&` in front of the command.

Answer (score 0):

use previous version  vscode-python extension

in my case, i solve it

Comment: Hi user11467397, I will try that, thanks!