# Visual Studio Code (VSC) python bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code

I have a problem, when running a python file, the &symbol appears in the bash. how do I remove it when I start the program?[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILob7.png)

Comment: Why are you running python scripts on mingw. Try it out on windows cmd

Comment: I recommend you replace your image with the actual text. The words in your image can't be searched and can't be read by people who rely in screen readers to consume webpages

Comment: This was previously asked as [vscode bash: syntax error near unexpected token &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618282/vscode-bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token) (and closed for not being reproducible -- just as this instance here _also_ doesn't provide enough details to tell someone how to reproduce the issue if they don't have the problem themselves already).

Comment: Also, error messages should always be given *as text*, not images, when asking questions here. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) on [meta].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ampersand "&" syntax error running any Python script in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456924/ampersand-syntax-error-running-any-python-script-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also had this problem. And I solved this.

- Don't use `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows`.
- Use this `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` as default.

This is my config.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
            "PowerShell": {
                "source": "PowerShell",
                "icon": "terminal-powershell"
            },
            "Command Prompt": {
                "path": [
                    "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                    "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
                ],
                "args": [],
                "icon": "terminal-cmd"
            },
            "Git Bash": {
                "source": "Git Bash",
                "icon": "terminal-bash"
            }
        },
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Scoop\\apps\\git\\current\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

And then restart VSCode.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late.

Take adventage of `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` instead of `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` for now.

You can take this as a workaround and wait for the next stable release of VSCode. On the `VSCode insiders` it has been solved.

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/16175) for more details.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Иван Кожухов Thanks for your reply. And could you provide the picture of the terminal outputs and the configuration of the settings.josn file?

Comment: @Иван Кожухов What's the difference between my answer with the answer you accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to run using MINGW which is not for python.
You can simply use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) to run your python code

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the command of the terminal to compile and run the target program, hoping to help you ~

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try to:

- restart vscode or your system
  or
- reselect the terminal using dropdown menu on the right side of your terminal.
  It should help and remove '&' from the beginning of the command prompt.