# my rock paper scissors game is not running on visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image: Screenshot]

I think something is wrong with this code it won't run. I'm using visual studio code.

When I run it displays:

& C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "c:/Users/user/New folder/main.py"

```
import random

isPlaying = True

li = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']

while isPlaying == True:

    computer_choice = random.choice(li)
    player_choice = input('Rock, paper or scissors? Use q to quit.\n').lower()


    if player_choice == computer_choice:
        print('Tie!')

    elif player_choice == 'rock':
        if computer_choice == 'scissors':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Win!')
        elif computer_choice == 'paper':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Lose!')

    elif player_choice == 'paper':
        if computer_choice == 'rock':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Win!')
        elif computer_choice == 'scissors':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Lose!')

    elif player_choice == 'scissors':
        if computer_choice == 'rock':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Lose!')
        
        elif computer_choice == 'paper':
            print(f'You chose {player_choice}, and the computer chose {computer_choice}!')
            print('Win!')

    elif player_choice == 'q':
        quit()

    else:
        print('Invalid choice, use rock, paper or scissors.')
```

Comment: You never set `isPlaying = False`. Why do you need that variable? Just use `while True:`

Comment: The script looks fine. I think this is a problem with using the VSCode console. Run the script from a regular command prompt.

Comment: It runs perfectly now, I don't know what's the problem with Visual Studio Code it runs in the python IDLE

Comment: How do I provide screenshots?

Comment: You don't have enough rep to add screenshots yet.

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: That picture only has text. Text should be copied-and-pasted into the question _as text_, not added as screenshots or pictures.

Comment: What commands do you use to start the program? Please list all of them in order.

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: Charles Duffy sorry I will read it, peer what commands?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456924/ampersand-syntax-error-running-any-python-script-in-vscode

Comment: No sorry, I will use IDLE or another code editor while I figure it out.

Comment: It looks like you are in a python shell. I don't think you should be. Instead of "when I run it" please state exactly what you type in the terminal from the very beginning (before the error occurs).

Comment: How are you running it via VSCode? For example, are you pressing the Play button at the top right? Are you using the Code Runner extension?

Comment: I fixed it, I had to click the delete button, beside the python shell, and then rerun it.

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: I clicked the play button, the one that comes after your install python ext in vscode.